# I cannot get JQuery Scroll Function to work on my site

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am attempting an effect much like the one seen on
https://codepen.io/michaeldoyle/pen/Bhsif?editors=0010
The problem is that, for some reason, it doesn't work at all on my
site http://pmoore17.altervista.org/TWADrama/index.php
I am trying to get the slideshow to phase out while the content phases
in, and vise versa. Help?

My JQuery:

```
    var hidetop = $("#hidetop");
    var range = $("#hidetop").height();
    var body = $("#wrapper");

    $(window).on('scroll', function() {

      var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
      var offset = hidetop.offset().top;
      var height = hidetop.outerHeight();
      offset = offset + height / 2;
      var calc = 1 - (scrollTop - offset + range) / range;

      hidetop.css({
        'opacity': calc
      });

      if (calc > '1') {
        hidetop.css({
          'opacity': 1
        });
      } else if (calc < '0') {
        hidetop.css({
          'opacity': 0
        });
      }

    });
```

My JQuery is currently deleted off my site because it was only
increasing load time and causing images not to load.

Comment: Can you put it back to you live site so I can see what is going on?

Comment: Seems to work as expected now... Do you still have an issue about this?

Comment: The images doesn't return back to full opacity on scroll back up... Play with the offset variable. Try set it to zero.

Comment: It works right now, but the problem is that it cuts out completely at a certain point instead of fading out slowly which is what I am looking for. @LouysPatriceBessette

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I got it.

Remove the division by 2 in `offset = offset + height / 2;`.

So like this: `offset = offset + height;`

Also, test it with a longer page.
or - just for the test - add this:

$("#wrapper").css({"height":2000});

Answer (score 0):

are you using your `scrip` in `head` element? if yes this might be the problem.. place your `<script> your function </script>` at the end of the document before closing the `</body>` tag.

Comment: Naah. This has nothing to do with OP problem.